# SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL and Highlighting Statements

Tags: sql-server

I write multiple SELECT statements in one window and normally highlight and run them as needed.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

SELECT * FROM Table1

SELECT * FROM Table2

SELECT * FROM Table3
```

This is an example of what my window might look like,  now from here I will *only* highlight `SELECT * FROM Table2`  and run it.

Will `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;` still apply even if it is not highlighted with the statement?

If it does still apply, *how* does it do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ignoring the usual spiel about why you shouldn't be using `READ UNCOMMITTED`...*

Setting the `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` applies at the connection level, until the connection is dropped or another level is set.

From [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173763.aspx):

> **SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL (Transact-SQL)**
>   Controls the locking and row versioning behavior of Transact-SQL statements issued by a connection to SQL Server.

So running this once in your SSMS query window will apply for all batched queries you send to the server within that connection (window).

Alternatively, you could add `WITH (NOLOCK)` to your statements to apply to individual ones, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1;
SELECT * FROM Table2 WITH (NOLOCK);
SELECT * FROM Table3;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, if you didn't execute it, it will not apply to your connection. As Chris mentioned in the previous answer, once you execute it in your connection (query windows in SSMS), all following queries in this connection will be executed using this transaction isolation level.

If you have doubts, you can check which transaction isolation level used for your connection right now:

```
DBCC USEROPTIONS
```